# How to convert quaternion rotation to steering wheel motion?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I'm creating a game where you use rotational remote(it knows only its rotation) to steer a car. I have a problem with converting `Quaternion`(this is the output of the controller) to steering wheel rotation.This is what is the closest to working form all the things that I have tried(transform.localRotation is a rotation of the steering wheel):

```
void Update() {

    transform.localRotation = GvrController.Orientation;

    transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(0.0f, 0.0f, transform.localRotation.z, transform.localRotation.w);

}
```

This obviously isn't a good solution and works not so well. There is a very simple visualization of what I'm trying to do:
[image]
Default orientation of the controller is facing forward as on the picture.

Basically the whole problem is how to skip all the axis other than the one responsible for rotating(axis 1 on the picture) and apply it to the steering wheel. Do you know how can I do this?

EDIT:
Because it's hard to explain the problem without proper visualization i took photos of my controller and drew axis on them.

This is the default orientation of the controller:

[image]

And this is how it's held with axis marked on it:

[image]

Comment: It would probably help if you gave some input and the expected output to better understand the rotation the controller gives you.

Comment: Yeah these are nasty to debug. I'd recommend recording test runs with approximate known expected output angles, then you can "reverse-engineer" the correct formula in any programming environment like Matlab or Python Spyder and then port it to the desired language / framework.

Comment: Can you please give us a recording with Euler conversion ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Quaternion.Euler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html) and [Quaternion.eulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html). Note the order for the Euler function is z, x then y, unlike Vector3. EulerAngles returns an angle in degrees (whereas rotation.x returns the quaternion amount for that axis). The Euler function expects an angle so you want something like:

```
Quaternion rot = GvrController.Orientation;
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rot.eulerAngles.z, 0, 0);
```

Depending on how the axes of your controller are set up you may need to experiment with other orientations if it's not y-up z-forward e.g.

```
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rot.eulerAngles.x, 0, 0);
```

or

```
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rot.eulerAngles.z);
```

and so on. It should soon become clear which system it uses.

Also, if the steering wheel is not parented to anything use rotation rather than localRotation.

Comment: I have same problem as before: it responds not only to the controller being rotated like a steering wheel but also to rotating it forward an backwards.

Comment: I meant to use use controllers orientation. Post updated. If the z axis is wrong just try the other axes.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It gives very inconsistant results - steering wheel changes direction of spinning or stops without me changing direction of rotation of the controller.  I tried all axis and any of them seems to correspond to the axis that I want the steering wheel to be rotating around.

Comment: What I have noticed is that all axis produce rotation even on one of them - when i set other axis to 0 its starts to behave weird. The other thing is that when controller is being rotated lets say on axis X tilting it on axis Y doesn't do the same thing as before rotating it around X axis.

Comment: Sounds like the controller might be giving a continuous feed rather than just saying "I'm at this angle now!". Debug.Log it's rotation in Update - is it constantly changing even when the controller is stationary? Also what happens when you just do transform.localRotation = GvrController.Orientation; by itself in Update?

Comment: The rotation of the controller is stable if it isn't moving and when simply `transform.localRotation = GvrController.Orientation;` it just rotates exactly like the controller. The axis seem to be allright when its rotated from its default position, but when using the rotated to the left position as a reference the axis seem to not be as i drew on the last picture.

Comment: Odd, this should work. What does the transform.eulerAngles log as when the controller is rotated to the left as in your picture? Also, as a quick and dirty fix you could add a rigidbody with freeze rotation on the offending axes.

Comment: This `Rigidbody` fix doesn't work because it affects only physics actions from what I know. When I did `Debug.Log(transform.localEulerAngles);` while holding it sideways it returns approximately `(0, 270, 90)`. I used `localEulerAngles` instead of `eulerAngles` because thats what I think you meant.